# Unable to make a matlab figure with no extra white space outside

Tags: matlab-figure

I want a matlab figure which contains no unnecessary white space outside of the borders of the figure. I have tried different things. For example

```
set(gca,'LooseInset',get(gca,'TightInset'))
```

But this removes the z-axis label. The user-made function "spaceplots" I am also unable to get to work (it returns nothing). The method described by MathWorks (https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/save-figure-with-minimal-white-space.html) also does not work.

So how can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
% creat some 3D plot:
x = 1:0.1:10;
y = x;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
f = @(x,y) sin(x).*cos(y);
Z = f(X,Y);
surf(X,Y,Z)
xlabel('Xsomething')
ylabel('Ysomething')
zlabel('Zsomething')

%%% here it starts: %%%
ax = gca;
post = findall(ax,'Type','Text'); % get all text handles
p = zeros(numel(post),2);
% collect all the position vectors:
for k = 1:numel(post)
    post(k).Units = 'normalized'; % set units to the normelized figure units
    % the 'position' of the text is relative to the axes, so we convert it
    % to the figure units:
    p(k,:) = post(k).Position(1:2)+ax.Position(1:2);
end
% find the most left and bottom items,
% and move them to the borders of the figure:
ax.Position(1:2) = min(p);
% fill the rest of the figure with th axes:
ax.Position(3:4) = 1-ax.Position(1:2);
```

**Before:**

[image: before]

**After:**

[image: after]

Comment: It gives an error for "ax.Position(1:2) = min(p);": In an assignment  A(:) = B, the number of elements in A and B must be the same.

Comment: Btw, so with this the white space gets filled by the figure. Will this affect the figure dimensions that I define in the script?

Comment: @Yoda, I don't get any error, did you try to run the code above o a fresh session of Matlab? What size is the resulting `p`?

Comment: @Yoda, as for your second comment, I don't understand what you mean. Try typing `axis tight`, and see if this helps.